# Create image, size relative to window width. Image not drawn when inserted in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cordova

I'm building a phonegap app (with jquery mobile) and trying to insert an image in my DOM with width relative to the window.outerWidth and height auto.

I've already tried placing the image in a div with relative width like so:

```
<div style="width:myRelativeWidth">
    <img style"width:100%; height:100%" src="somePath>
</div>
```

This works great, except on the iPhone where it sets the height of the image (auto) too late. It will be the correct width, but it is stretched heightwise to its original size before it is sized to the correct aspect ratio.

To counteract this, I've tried to scale it in relation to the size of the original image. The only way I know to get this is by preloading the image and setting the size before it is inserted in the DOM by the following function

```
imageElement = new Image();
imageElement.src = path;

setImageSize(widthPercentage);

function setImageSize(widthPercentage) { 
    var pageWidth = window.outerWidth;
    var pageHeight = window.outerHeight;
    var imageWidth = imageElement.width;
    var imageHeight = imageElement.height;
    var calculatedImageWidth;
    var calculatedImageHeight;
    var scaleFactor;

    if(widthPercentage) {
        calculatedImageWidth = pageWidth * (widthPercentage / 100);
        scaleFactor = calculatedImageWidth / imageWidth;
        calculatedImageHeight = imageHeight * scaleFactor;
        imageElement.width = calculatedImageWidth;
        imageElement.height = calculatedImageHeight;
    }
}

document.body.appendChild(imageElement);
```

But testing in the browser i don't get the image when loading the page, but i get it when refreshing it.
Some googling told me that I have a problem with the image being loaded in the cache, but not drawn.

How can i force the image to be drawn?

Comment: Call your function on the `load` event of the image, so that its dimensions are already know when you try to read them.

Comment: @CBroe No luck with onload. I'm trying to recreate the scenario on a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbjorge/7WCBT/5/), but I'm unable. I'm not sure if this is a problem related to phonegap or if there are different set of security rules when using `new Image()` since i'm loading a relative path (to a local file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer!

Assign the onload method to `setImageSize` as mentioned by @CBroe, and place it  **before** `imageElement.src=`.